# Using a stored procedure to (+1 or -1) a value from a table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a button event that has to disable itself after a certain number of users is reached.

We are storing the currently accessed user count in the db, and I am trying to create a stored procedure, that when called, will automatically increment the user count on that table.
*I am going to create a separate procedure to subtract.*

In my mind, I would need to get the current value, add one, then save it in the table, bringing me to this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procDrRefBooksAddUser 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fileId int = NULL,
    @count int = 0,
    @newCount int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT UserCount FROM tblDrRefBooks WHERE DrRefBookFileID = @fileId
    SET @count = UserCount

    SET @newCount = @count + 1

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE tblDrRefBooks SET tblDrRefBooks.UserCount = @newCount WHERE DrRefBookFileID = @fileId
END
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to get it right, coming up with errors such as:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure procDrRefBooksAddUser, Line 17
Invalid column name 'UserCount'
```

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong.

**Edit:** Update on answer (finally)

My SQL is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procDrRefBooksAddUser] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fileId int = NULL,
    @newCount int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tblDrRefBooks
    SET @newCount = UserCount = UserCount + 1
    WHERE DrRefBookFileID = @fileId
    SELECT @newCount AS iden

END
```

And code behind is:

```
 using (SqlConnection db = DataConn.SqlConnection())
                {
                    db.Open();
                    SqlTransaction transaction = db.BeginTransaction();

                    try
                    {
                        lbltest.Text = "Starting...";
                       using (SqlCommand acommand =
                            new SqlCommand(
                                "EXEC procDrRefBooksAddUser @fileID, @count",
                                db, transaction) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
                        {
                            acommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fileID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Int32.Parse(location.Value);
                            acommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@count", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

                            using (SqlDataReader rdr = acommand.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                btnLoad.Text = "Here: " + rdr["iden"];
                            }
                        }

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ea)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        lbltest.Text = ("Insertion Error: " + ea.Message);
                    }
                }
```

But I get this error: `Insertion Error: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @count = UserCount
```

is incorrect. You can't access columns from previous `SELECT` statements like that.

You can just do it all in one atomic statement. This increments the column and sets the output parameter with the new value of UserCount.

```
UPDATE tblDrRefBooks
SET    @newCount = UserCount = UserCount + 1
WHERE  DrRefBookFileID = @fileId
```

This avoids race conditions from reading and writing the value in separate operations.

Comment: Seems legit :/ Just trying to get my code to issue the statement properly, then I'll mark the answer ^^

Comment: When trying to read the @newCount (as iden) - it says `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present`

Comment: @NewAmbition You don't need to use a DataReader as it doesn't return any result set. Just use ExecuteNonQuery then get the value from the output parameter

Comment: @MartinSmith - I think I had used a reader with my previous `Output Parameter` - I have no idea of any other way.

Answer (score 1):

For reference case, it should be like this

```
SELECT @Count = UserCount FROM tblDrRefBooks WHERE DrRefBookFileID = @fileId
@newCount = @Count + 1
```

But you can just avoid that and do this instead

```
UPDATE tblDrRefBooks SET UserCount = UserCount + 1
WHERE 
   DrRefBookFileID = @fileId AND
   UserCount < @MaxUserCount
```

### Update

Notice I added `AND UserCount < @MaxUserCount`. Your stored procedure might not capture all the count as page refreshes quickly [race condition]. You may have an old @Count value.

- Make sure the count is only increase if MAX is not reached
- Just get the count at any point in time with another PROC. Don't do it in the same PROC as for updating count as you can get OLD count value
- Can have a flag on your table that is SET in the PROC once MAX is reached

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in your procedure :

SELECT @count=UserCount FROM tblDrRefBooks WHERE DrRefBookFileID = @fileId

Answer (score 0):

no need to use temporary variables and use of select query.
try this..

```
UPDATE tblDrRefBooks 
SET tblDrRefBooks.UserCount = UserCount +1 
WHERE DrRefBookFileID = @fileId
```